# Is it possible for Castle Windsor to resolve types loaded after an application starts?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Say I setup my app.config to specify a type that my current application knows nothing about. Then I use AppDomain.Load(byte[]) to load the assembly before instantiating an instance of my WindsorContainer.

Can Windsor resolve the type? Here's an example:

Castle config:

```
<castle>
 <components>
   <component id="test" service="Application.Services.ITestService, Application.Services" type="TestLibrary.TestService, TestLibrary"/>
 </components>
</castle>
```

Then in my code:

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("TestLibrary.dll");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(buffer);

/* the assembly is now loaded and if I iterate AppDomain.GetAssemblies() is shows there */

WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());/* here I get  "The type name TestLibrary.TestService, TestLibrary could not be located" */

ITestService resolvedService = container.Resolve<ITestService>("test");
```

**Edit:**

I've found that this does work:

```
Assembly testLibrary = Assembly.LoadFile("TestLibrary.dll");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(testLibrary.GetName());

WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
ITestService service = container.Resolve<ITestService>("test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the assembly after registering Windsor components (as I assumed from your original question), it doesn't work since it can't know about those types until their assembly is loaded. You could use the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad` event and register those types there. Here's a sample:

```
[Test]
public void AssemblyLoadRegisterFromXml() {
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += (sender, args) => {
        var filename = args.LoadedAssembly.FullName.Split(',')[0] + ".xml";
        container.Install(Configuration.FromXmlFile(filename));
    }; ;
    Assembly.Load("System.Transactions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
    var ex = container.Resolve(Type.GetType("System.Transactions.TransactionException, System.Transactions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"));
    Assert.AreEqual("hello world", ex.GetType().GetProperty("Message").GetValue(ex, null));
}
```

And have a System.Transactions.xml file with the components configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <components>
    <component id="txex" type="System.Transactions.TransactionException, System.Transactions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <parameters>
        <message>hello world</message>
      </parameters>
    </component>
  </components>
</configuration>
```

Now that you state that you're loading the assembly through `AppDomain.Current.Load(byte[])` before Windsor initialization, I can say that your problem is actually not with Windsor but with `AppDomain.Current.Load(byte[])` semantics, see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/390e7740-c209-49cc-b890-d4c880e82494) for an explanation.

Comment: You say "it can't know about those types until their assembly is loaded", but I AM loading the assembly first. I posted an example.

Comment: Also, my version of Windsor apparently doesn't expose an Install method

Comment: Get Windsor 2.0, that featured has been included over a year ago ( http://fisheye2.atlassian.com/changelog/castleproject/?cs=4874 ).
If it doesn't work with the latest version please file a bug report

Comment: I swear I downloaded the 2.0 version originally, but I guess I was wrong. In any occasion, I don't think I need the Install method anyway.

Comment: Your problem has actually nothing to do with Windsor. See AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load behavior here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/390e7740-c209-49cc-b890-d4c880e82494